# iPhone playing music in background with mixing and remote control

Tags: iphone, ios, session, audio, remote-control

My application requires following settings in audio session category to work as intended:

`AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` and `kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers` =set to true (*"Plays audio in background"* also set in Info.plist file).

Is there a way to make application with those settigns receive remote control events (from earpiece) and prevent iTunes from kicking in?

I am able to receive remote control events when my application is in the background and `kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers` is set to `false` (default behaviour) but when I fine-tune it to `true`, iTunes intercepts remote control events EVEN IF my application is in foreground.

**Am I doomed to compromise on either mixable behaviour or remote controls functionality or is there a way around it?**